# How can I "turn off" automatically-added dashes in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, text-formatting

I added text like this to a document:

```
— Oui, monsieur.
— Bien. Quelle heure avez-vous ?
— Onze heures vingt-deux, répondit Passepartout, en tirant des profondeurs de son gousset une énorme montre d'argent.
```

...and then added some more on the next page like this:

```
"The new servant," said he.

A young man of thirty advanced and bowed.

"You are a Frenchman, I believe," asked Phileas Fogg, "and your name is John?"
```

...but instead of copying as above, it copied over with dashes preceding each paragarph like the previous page; apparently once that "style" has begun, it keeps up until specifically turned off - but how can I do that (turn off that formatting)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's pretty blamed easy: mash the Enter key another time to 86 the undesired style. Then you can backspace to put the cursor back to where you want it.